# Match name of location with zip code from tab seperated TXT file using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a form that the user fills out and they need to enter their zip code. I would therefore like to retrieve the location name of the zip code from a large TXT file containing tab-separated data with zip codes and location names. The zip code is on column 1, while location name is on column 2.

```
2058    SESSVOLLMOEN    0235    ULLENSAKER  G
2060    GARDERMOEN  0235    ULLENSAKER  G
2061    GARDERMOEN  0235    ULLENSAKER  P
2062    JESSHEIM    0235    ULLENSAKER  P
2063    JESSHEIM    0235    ULLENSAKER  G
2066    JESSHEIM    0235    ULLENSAKER  G
2067    JESSHEIM    0235    ULLENSAKER  G
2068    JESSHEIM    0235    ULLENSAKER  G
2069    JESSHEIM    0235    ULLENSAKER  G
```

My `$input` contains '`2069`'. How can I get the city/location name of `$input`?

Comment: After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527). You'd think someone with 3K rep would know this.

Comment: The most efficient solution will probably involve ingesting that data into a database and loading it from there. Do you have a database?

Answer (score 1):

It would've have helped if you provided some examples of what you've already tried and where you're stuck. I'm assuming you're fairly new to php and probably don't know where to look. Here is a piece of code that should work for you:

```
function searchForValue($val, $table_array) {
   foreach ($table_array as $row_string) {
       $row_array = explode ("\t", $row_string);  //this is a single row converted into a one dimensional array 

       if ($row_array[0] == $val) {
           return ($row_array[1]) ; //second column in the row that contains the city name
           break;
       }
   }
   return null;
}

//Read the file contents, assuming file is in the same directory  
$text = file_get_contents('SampleText.txt', true);
//Convert the string with all file contents to an array of strings, where each element is a string value corresponding to a row in the file 
$zip_table_array = explode("\r\n", $text);
$zip_to_search = '2069'; 

$city = searchForValue($zip_to_search, $zip_table_array);

echo ("<br>City for zip $zip_to_search is: " . $city ) ;
```

Hope this helps.